# MongoDB query using $ projection operator in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am doing a search in MongoDB and it is working well but when I want to do the same query in Java it does not work that I want.

This my query in Mongo (it is working)

```
db.DondeIr.find( {'places.log_lat': { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ -99.1565997,19.4275985 ], 0.5/6371 ] } }},{_id: 0, 'places.$': 1})
```

Here is the query in java.

```
BasicDBObject geometery = new BasicDBObject("$centerSphere", asList(
            asList(-99.1565997, 19.4275985), 0.5 / 6371));

    BasicDBObject operator = new BasicDBObject("$geoWithin", geometery);
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("places.log_lat", operator);
```

I think it is because I am not using projection operator "$" in java, so I do not have an idea how can I do. help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add `BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0).append("places.$", 1);` and `dbCollection.find(query, projection)`

Comment: Thank you so much for that, it really is working for me. Thank you.